# Nested for loop not working in makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to use a nested for loop for searching and copying some files inside the recipe of one of the targets inside a makefile:

```
DIR = $(DIR_A) $(DIR_B)

install:
      for dirs in $(DIR); do \
        for file in $(shell find $(dirs) -type f -and -not -path "*/.svn*" | sed -e "s|$(dirs)||"); do \
        folder=$${file%/*}; \
          $(INSTALL) -d $(DEST_DIR)$$folder/log; \
          $(INSTALL) $(dirs)/$$file $(DEST_DIR)$$folder/log; \
        done \
      done
```

However $(dirs) variable always evaluates to empty inside the second for loop and the current working directory gets passed to "find" instead of first directory path from $(DIR).

Can someone please suggest if I am missing something ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `$(dirs)` in the find command is being expanded by make to the make variable `dirs` which is unset and thus the empty string.  To reference the shell variable, you need to escape the `$`:

```
 for file in $$(find $${dirs} -type f -and \
      -not -path "*/.svn*" | sed -e "s|$${dirs}||"); do
```

But don't do this.  It is much cleaner to explicitly list the files you intend to install.  If there are many, it is fine to write a script to generate the Makefile.  What you are doing is a fragile mess.

Comment: I have tried adding echoing the value of "dirs" just after the first for loop. but it evaluates to empty :

Comment: You can't use `$(dir)` as a shell variable reference: shell variables can't use parentheses.  It should be either `$dir` or `${dir}`, so in the make command it should be either `$$dir` or `$${dir}`.  Ditto for `$(dirs)`.

Comment: @MadScientist Yes, of course.  Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Sorry guys, my example never used $(dir). Are you referring to $(DIR) instead ?

Comment: Ok, I have tried using the expression posted by @WilliamPursell but still I am running into the same problem. The problem seems like more to be about how to pass loop variable to shell function. The loop variable evaluates to empty when it gets passed to the shell function irrespective of $$dirs or $${dirs}.

Comment: I have a bit simplified example to reproduce this :
for dirs in $(DIR); do \
          for file in $(shell ls $$dirs); do \
            echo "file is $$file"; \
          done \
        done
$$dirs evaluates to empty and contents of the current directory are displaced instead of the one that should be pointed out by $$dirs value.

Answer (score 0):

You have made several errors, and you will find it almost impossible to solve them as l;ong as you insist on trying to solve them all at once.

Let's try this in stages. Suppose your `DIR_A` and `DIR_B` are `north` and `south`. On the command line, if you try this:

```
for dirs in north south; do echo $dirs; done
```

you will get the correct output:

```
north
south
```

If you try it as a makefile rule:

```
install:
    for dirs in $(DIR); do echo $$dirs; done
```

again, it works correctly.

If you try your makefile recipe:

```
install:
    for dirs in $(DIR); do \ for file in $(shell ls $$dirs); do \ echo "file is $$file"; \ done \ done
```

it fails, because Make expands the `$(shell ...)` command before passing the entire `for` command to the shell, when `dirs` has not yet been assigned a value. One way to construct a sensible shell command is to use backticks:

```
for dirs in north south; do for file in `ls $dirs`; do  echo "file is $file";  done  done
```

This works on the command line. A makefile rule built around it:

```
install:
    for dirs in $(DIR); do for file in `ls $$dirs`; do  echo "file is $$file";  done  done
```

also works.

That should be enough to allow you to rewrite your makefile.