# How to pass for loop variable to shell function in makefile

Tags: loops, makefile, scripting, gnu-make

Consider the makefile below :

```
CFG_DIR = /media/test/
all:
    for list in $(CFG_DIR); do \
      echo "list is $$list"; \
      for file in $(shell ls $${list}); do \
        echo "file is $$file"; \
      done \
    done
```

When make is executed the below result is generated:

```
list is /media/test/
file is Makefile
```

Instead of printing the directory listing of /media/test/ directory, directory listing of the current directory from where the make command is executed is printed.

It seems like within the shell function $$list is being evaluated to an empty value. It would be helpful if someone can point out the correct way to access for loop variables inside shell function.

Comment: This seems to be identical to [your question of a few hours previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352145/nested-for-loop-not-working-in-makefile).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a shell variable in a make function.

Consider how make works: when it wants to run a recipe command FIRST it expands all the make variables and functions in the command, THEN it takes the resulting string and passes it to a shell to run, THEN it waits for the shell to exit.  If the shell exits with a success code (0) then make says "yay it worked!"  If the shell exits with a failure code (non-0) then make says "boo it failed."

Here's your recipe:

```
for list in $(CFG_DIR); do \
  echo "list is $$list"; \
  for file in $(shell ls $${list}); do \
    echo "file is $$file"; \
  done \
done
```

So, FIRST make will expand this including all variables and functions.  You have a `$(CFG_DIR)` variable, and a `$(shell...)` function.  The variable is simply `/media/test/`.  When make expands the function, it sees the command to pass to the shell is `ls ${list}`.  So make runs:

```
/bin/sh -c 'ls ${list}'
```

Well, unless you've set the shell variable `list` in your environment somewhere it's the empty string, so the shell executes `ls` and returns all the contents of your current directory.  Then, make substitutes that into your recipe, and hands the results to the shell to run:

```
/bin/sh -c 'for list in /media/test; do
  echo "list is $list";
  for file in <current-wd-files>; do
    echo "file is $file";
  done
done'
```

So.  Moral of the story: in a recipe command you're *already* in a shell.  So you should *never* use the `$(shell ...)` make function.  It will only lead to confusion and sorrow.

You should use shell syntax since you already have a shell:

```
all:
      for list in $(CFG_DIR); do \
          echo "list is $$list"; \
          for file in `ls $${list}`; do \
            echo "file is $$file"; \
          done \
        done
```